# Delay on Lemmon Slider item with Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, slideshow

On the home page of our site, the 3 large images are part of a Lemmon Slider.

http://www.finecooking.com

On all browsers, there is a noticeable holdup in loading the 3rd image.  In IE9, it's considerable and I've been tasked to solve this.

It seems that the Facebook module could be holding it up, but even with that removed this still happens.  Thoughts on what to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like that's an issue with Lemmon Slider, try loading up their homepage:

http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php

I noticed the same issue as your website on theirs, where the last visible image of the slider has a "noticeable holdup" (note: there are 4 visible images on the lemmon slider homepage, and I am referring to the 4th image loading slow).

I even noticed your finecooking.com lemmon slider was acting a bit buggy. If you load the page and try to slide backwards, it won't allow it. But, if you slide to the right first, and then slide back to the left, the carousel will jerk forward, and you will see the last image on your carousel (Going to SF Chefs? Image), after this you can slide back and forward but the carousel will jerk every time you past the first image to the last image (infinite scrolling).

Do you have to use Lemmon Slider? I would imagine it might take longer to try and debug and fix a problem with the library api's core than to just use one of the many jquery carousel slider plugins available on the internet that work these type of issues.

If you only need the minimal basic features of a carousel slider, try this one: http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/ which I've used before and seems to work just fine. Good luck!

Comment: I ditched Lemmon slider. Using Flexslider now.  I needed something that was responsive.  Thanks.